# C# Monogame error due to directories

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, directory

I've recently started learning code on my free time with a few friends, and we just recently started on a tohou-esque game together. Instead of coding on seperate computers, we usually take turns on one laptop with Visual Studio on it. However, when I downloaded the program of drive, I got this wierd error which I have no idea how to solve, and I cant find any help on google or programming forums.

What we use: Visual studio with Monogame.

The Error that we observe:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Error The source file
>   "c:\users\boman\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TouhouPara\TouhouPara\Content\bin\Windows\" is actually a directory.
>   The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.

Comment: Do you have a pre-build or post-build event that is running? What file/line does it tell you the error is in?

Comment: It does not tell me which line, there is not a error in the code itself, since it worked on my friends computer. 

When I try to start the build, it simply tells me that there were build errors, and asks me if I want to run the last sucsessful build, which works fine.  

The same error occur if I try to create a new project and then copy paste all the code into it. So I don't think its a problem with the exported file either.